# NPE when using @CircuitBreaker

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

Iám trying to implement resilience4j using spring annotation @CircuitBreaker. I have 2 microservices: order-service and inventory-service. Order-service has a post method in controller that uses a service to call the inventory. Everything works fine until i add the @CircuitBreaker annotation. When i add it i get a nullPointerException on the service.
Here is the exception: [this is the exception i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QjrH.png)
OrderController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/order")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class OrderController {

    private final OrderService orderService;

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @CircuitBreaker(name = "inventory", fallbackMethod = "fallbackMethod")
    private String placeOrder(@RequestBody OrderRequest orderRequest) {
        orderService.placeOrder(orderRequest);
        return "Order placed successfully!";
    }

    public String fallbackMethod(OrderRequest orderRequest, RuntimeException runtimeException) {
        return "Oops! Something went wrong, please order after some time!";
    }
}
<br/>
```

OrderService:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Transactional
public class OrderService {
    private final OrderRepository orderRepository;
    private final WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;
    public void placeOrder(OrderRequest orderRequest) {
        Order order = new Order();
        order.setOrderNumber(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

        List<OrderLineItems> orderLineItems = orderRequest.getOrderLineItemsDtoList()
                .stream()
                .map(this::mapToDto)
                .toList();

        order.setOrderLineItemsList(orderLineItems);

        List<String> skuCodes = order.getOrderLineItemsList().stream().map(OrderLineItems::getSkuCode).toList();

        //Call inventory service and place order if product is in stock
        InventoryResponse[] inventoryResponseArray = webClientBuilder.build().get()
                .uri("http://inventory-service/api/inventory",
                        uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.queryParam("skuCode", skuCodes).build())
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(InventoryResponse[].class)
                .block();

        boolean allProductsInStock = Arrays.stream(inventoryResponseArray).allMatch(InventoryResponse::isInStock);
        if(allProductsInStock) {
            orderRepository.save(order);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Product is not in stock!");
        }
    }

    private OrderLineItems mapToDto(OrderLineItemsDto orderLineItemsDto) {
        OrderLineItems orderLineItems = new OrderLineItems();
        orderLineItems.setPrice(orderLineItemsDto.getPrice());
        orderLineItems.setQuantity(orderLineItemsDto.getQuantity());
        orderLineItems.setSkuCode(orderLineItemsDto.getSkuCode());
        return orderLineItems;
    }
}
```

properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/order-service
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

server.port=8081

eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://eureka:password@localhost:8761/eureka
spring.application.name=order-service

management.health.circuitbreakers.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always

#Resilience4j Properties
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.inventory.registerHealthIndicator=true
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.inventory.event-consumer-buffer-size=10
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.inventory.slidingWindowType=COUNT_BASED
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.inventory.slidingWindowSize=5
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.inventory.failureRateThreshold=50
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.inventory.waitDurationInOpenState=5s
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.inventory.permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState=3
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.inventory.automaticTransitionFromOpenToHalfOpenEnabled=true
```

I tried to use resilience4j with spring annotation @CircuitBreaker and instead of working fine it makes my spring context not to load my service bean.

Comment: Please embed the relevant code in your post. Links change.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar i hope now i have done it right. It is my first time posting.

Comment: @CristianDinica Please try to use `Throwable` instead of RuntimeException in fallback method.

Comment: Also, try placing circuit breaker in service instead of on controller.

Comment: @doptimusprime placing circuit breaker in service class solves the problem, but i would like to understand why i get npe when using it in the controller class.

Comment: @CristianDinica It seems due to weaving of PostMapping and CircuitBreaker, it may result in a different class or object which is causing NPE.